# adding data to the database from Production to Dev

Tags: foreach, datatable, addition

Here, We dev people sort of work in our own world if we can't get prives, then to bad figure it out in code and don't even bother with asking for a production database to be backed to a development environment.  So I have two databases one called prod and the other call dev. We really never need to update all the tables at one time just the ones that pertain to our application at the time (there is to many table to do all with out a back up process)
so given that I have tried a couple of ideas that I actually got from here (at least one of them). Each piece of code executes but when I go to the Dev Table no data :(
Permission is not an issue "this time".

(1) 
   DataRow[] rowstoCopy;
     rowstoCopy = tdProd.Select();
                foreach (DataRow temp in rowstoCopy)
                {
                    tdDev.ImportRow(temp);
                }

(2) 
 dsProd.Tables.Add(tdProd);
                dsDev.Tables.Add(tdDev);

```
            foreach(DataTable thisTable in dsProd.Tables)
            {
                DataRow DevRow;
              // For each row, print the values of each column.
                foreach(DataRow myRow in thisTable.Rows)
                {
                    DevRow = tdDev.NewRow();
                    int i = thisTable.Columns.Count -1;(could use an Array but fustration set in)
                    foreach(DataColumn myCol in thisTable.Columns)
                    {
                       DevRow[i - 1] = myRow[myCol].ToString();
                       Console.WriteLine(myRow[myCol]);
                        i += 1;
                    }

                    tdDev.Rows.Add(DevRow);

                   }
                Console.WriteLine(tdDev.Rows.Count);
            }
```

Everthing runs and printout to the console with now errors all however when I go to the dev table there are NO records. The second one really bugs me this would be very handy for an end user

Comment: Specifying what language this is would help.

Comment: I solved it (not number 2 that one still haunts me) 
`code`string strSQL = "INSERT INTO [SQLDEV].[dbo]." + to_tb + " SELECT * FROM [SQLProd].[dbo]." + from_tb; // Console.WriteLine(strSQL.ToString()); Console.Read(); SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn); cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; conn.Open(); cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); conn.Close();`code`

Answer (score 0):

yeah that did it

string strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Ops1SQLDEV].[dbo]." + to_tb + " SELECT * FROM [Ops1SQL].[dbo]." + from_tb;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();